# protocol not found java.net.MalformedURLException

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, malformedurlexception

```
public static Bitmap downloadImage(String link) {
    Bitmap myBitmap = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        System.out.println("Working");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        System.out.println("connection open");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        System.out.println("connect");
        System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
        try {
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
            Log.v("ERROR", "Errorchence : " + e);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return myBitmap;
}
```

I am trying to download an image from server.Here is the link which i am trying [image](https://byteshaft-bidder.s3.amazonaws.com/media/images/1e06d5c5-1542-4be1-8f8f-a4bc6ba9820b.png)

I tried wget from terminal and its working fine. 
It says protocol not found but https is there in url as u can see the log tag
I have attached
[logtag](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14418177/)

Comment: Retry your code again. I was able to reproduce your issue but it's gone without code modification. Also you could remove connection.setDoInput(true); connection.connect(); just put inputStream in BitmapFactory.decodeStream

Comment: i tried again and again but still having crash

Comment: did you configure Internet Connection inside manifest.xml File ?

Comment: Maybe you could use `HttpsURLConnection` instead of `HttpURLConnection`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html

Comment: @StephaneM tried but no luck

Comment: problem solved actually the url was enclosed in quotes.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and help :)